# Can MySQL seamlessly be replaced with MariaDB or are there things to change in this case?

Tags: php, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

If I replace a MySQL 5.1 server with a MariaDB Server (Maria & XtraDB storages) instead of MySQL (MyISAM & InnoDB), will most of MySQL client software (incl. applications made with PHP 5.2 and Java SE 1.6) ...

1. just remain working without any changes (with minor regressions maybe)?
2. Or will I have to replace/reconfigure client drivers (like use another JDBC driver class and connection string)?
3. Or will I have even to change application code?

Comment: @cherouvim, I suppose you probably have a clue ;-)

Comment: does it relate with the word "oracle"?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a less Oracle-dependent and more progressive (as XtraDB is compared to InnoDB, AFAIK) solution. I am pretty conservative in taking in mind market panics and hypes, but now even I go uncomfortable relying on Oracle's goodwill :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

http://kb.askmonty.org/v/mariadb-versus-mysql

> All MySQL connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL C connector etc) works unchanged with MariaDB.

Comment: Succinct, yet perfect.

Comment: This is not entirely true.  MariaDB has two levels of password encryption: old and new.  If your DB account is configured to use the old method, mysql connectors cannot connect to it.

Comment: [Erick Robertson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/300311/erick-robertson)
I think we faced the same problem, So how to solve it? I got backup of MySql (mysqldump) and upgraded MySql to MariaDB  so now I am Restored the database to MariaDB  and Iam not able to See the Table's data
If you know the solution please ansewear me

Answer (score 1):

I have used Mariadb as replacement for Oracle's MySQL for years. It is faster and very reliable. Needs just little attention in apt, but nothing severe. Also, there is one small detail with Mariadb; it is seeing [error] "PHP Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch" in the logs. I haven't found any other solution to that other than to start manually compiling: [askMonty](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/installation-issues-with-php5/).

```
$php -i | grep 'Client API'

Client API version => 5.3.7-MariaDB
Client API library version => 5.3.7-MariaDB
Client API header version => 5.1.61
Client API version => 5.3.7-MariaDB
```

Answer (score 1):

> just remain working without any changes (with minor regressions
>   maybe)?

You shouldn't have any issues as long as you replace with the same version. If you're currently are using MySQL 5.1, you can replace with MariaDB 5.1. If you are using 5.5, use the corresponding one. MariaDB v5.2 and v5.3 and enhanced versions of 5.1.

> Or will I have to replace/reconfigure client drivers (like use another
>   JDBC driver class and connection string)?

You shouldn't. MySQL and MariaDB both use the same protocol and overall syntax, but there could be a few exceptions in some cases. The URL quoted in another answer is a great resource: http://kb.askmonty.org/v/mariadb-versus-mysql

Regarding the drivers' licenses, there are differences if you plan to distribute your project commercially. In that case I recommend you to double check the license terms and if you have any concerns, use the MariaDB/SkySQL versions of the connectors as suggested in another answer. Check http://www.skysql.com/downloads/java-cc-connectors-mariadb for details.

> Or will I have even to change application code?

The application code should be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little feedback requarding the compatibility with mysql driver/CodeIgniter. I ran into the problems on BIT attributes types few minutes ago.

Value was not retrived from the server. It was always empty.
I was using standard CI database configuration which is using "mysql" driver.
After changing driver in the database.php to "mysqli" problem was solved.

Just the heads up that there can be some differences if you are using old mysql driver.

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

MariaDB client API version 5.5.40

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is MySQL evolved.

It is also the same developer who is behind MySQL and MariaDB. It is almost the same (if it is not, i can only say MariaDB is MySQL improved, dot).

**You don't have to change nothing in your PHP.**

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to popular belief, the default Connector/J JDBC driver for connecting to and interacting with MySQL in Java does not play nicely with MariaDB. To work with MariaDB, you need to have your application use the Drizzle or SkySQL driver.

http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-faq-is-there-any-java-connector-for-mariadb-than-the-one-from-mysql

Comment: I've read the article you've linked to and I can't see what'e the point there. Moreover, it says that there are no reasons to replace the connector and there is a comment saying Drizzle is not complete.